# What are uri in issue action of eosio.nft contract , Do we really need this?

Tags: eosio.token, ico

I go through this repo https://github.com/unicoeos/eosio.nft and **set contract** and **provide permission** successfully on my local nodeos.

I successfully created a token **CCN** but  I am not able to push the action issue.
issue action is like :

```
void nft::issue( account_name to,
                     asset quantity,
                     vector<string> uris,
                     string name,
                     string memo)
    {

    eosio_assert( is_account( to ), "to account does not exist");

        // e,g, Get EOS from 3 EOS
        symbol_type symbol = quantity.symbol;
        eosio_assert( symbol.is_valid(), "invalid symbol name" );
        eosio_assert( symbol.precision() == 0, "quantity must be a whole number" );
        eosio_assert( memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes" );

    eosio_assert( name.size() <= 32, "name has more than 32 bytes" );
    eosio_assert( name.size() > 0, "name is empty" );

        // Ensure currency has been created
        auto symbol_name = symbol.name();
        currency_index currency_table( _self, symbol_name );
        auto existing_currency = currency_table.find( symbol_name );
        eosio_assert( existing_currency != currency_table.end(), "token with symbol does not exist, create token before issue" );
        const auto& st = *existing_currency;

        // Ensure have issuer authorization and valid quantity
        require_auth( st.issuer );
        eosio_assert( quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity" );
        eosio_assert( quantity.amount > 0, "must issue positive quantity of NFTs" );
        eosio_assert( symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch" );

        // Increase supply
    add_supply( quantity );

        // Check that number of tokens matches uri size
        eosio_assert( quantity.amount == uris.size(), "mismatch between number of tokens and uris provided" );

        // Mint nfts
        for(auto const& uri: uris) {
            mint( to, st.issuer, asset{1, symbol}, uri, name);
        }

        // Add balance to account
        add_balance( to, quantity, st.issuer );
    }
```

My question is what is uris here? Is this is a vector of all tokens that i have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass some unique string for every token.
For an example if you want to issue 2 token then you need to run this command

> `cleos push action ac_name issue '["ac_name2","2 CCN",["firsttoken","secondtoken"],"This is MEMO"]' -p ac_name`

Try this.

Comment: Yes this is true, but what is the significance of this, because uri and id both are store in the table.

Comment: May be if you use it in game development likely to develop different avtars(or unique assets) you can set own uri of that purpose.